# show and hide html element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem may be very simple to you so please don't get angry :D
I'm junior developer and I'm little bad at javascript.
I have a form like this :

**IMAGE :**

[image]

When I choose "*count view*", the input with lable "*view*" show up, and when I continue choose "*count clic*k", the input with lable "*click*" show up too.

**Javascript** code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on("click","#count_option", function(e){
        if($("#count_option").val() === $("#count_view").val()) {
            $("#view_form").show();
        }
        if($("#count_option").val() === $("#count_click").val()) {
            $("#click_form").show();
        }
    });
});
```

I want when i choose an option, just one input show up. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share your html too ?

Comment: Hi, where do you close the view_form and click_form? if you want to show one form and not another, you need a check to see if the other form is showing, and if it is, hide it.

Comment: I was asking about html code

Comment: @Spangle or just hide them both and show the one you want.

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya it's very basic, just one thing is the two last input have style="display:none;"

Comment: @VuongPhamQuan, check the answer, hide one form while you want to open to another one and vice-versa. I was asking so that I can share you the full code in any online editor

Comment: If you're still stuck, please post your HTML. Or better yet give us a working example in a snippet.

Comment: thank everybody, I don't know it's so simple like that. I figured out. So embarrass :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to hide other form when you want to see the another one and vice-versa. 
Check the code below, change few things and you'll be good to go.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on("click","#count_option", function(e){
        if($("#count_option").val() === $("#count_view").val()) {
            $("#view_form").show();
            $("#click_form").hide(); // hide other form
        }
        if($("#count_option").val() === $("#count_click").val()) {
            $("#click_form").show();
            $("#view_form").hide(); // hide other form
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yup it was a simple issue.